# Python function dereferences a pointer but still alters the original list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pointers, dereference

I was playing around with python for the last few days and I keep getting a weird problem. (For reference, I'm working on project euler's 345.) 
So... I'm trying to zero a row and a column of a 2D array, but not the point where they intersect. Now, I understand that there might be a more pythonic way of solving this, but I'm mainly concerned with why the code I have here isn't working.

```
def choose(initial_grid,row,col):
  """Return a grid with a given row and column zeroed except where intersect.
  """
  grid = list(initial_grid)                 #FLAG 1
  Special_value = grid[row][col] 
  grid[row] = [0]*len(grid[row]) 
  for i in xrange(len(grid)):
    grid[i][col] = 0
  grid[row][col] = Special_value
  return grid
qwer = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [ 9,10,11,12],
        [13,14,15,16]]
print choose(qwer,1,1)
print qwer
```

Anyways, I'd expect the function output to be

```
[[1, 0, 3, 4], [0, 6, 0, 0], [9, 0, 11, 12], [13, 0, 15, 16]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

But... It isn't. For whatever reason, `qwer` gets its column 1 cleared. I've tried doing a list copy to dereference the pointer passed by `initial_grid,` and I've tried using `grid = initial_grid[:]`, but nothing seems to work.

So what's wrong? How do I fix this? And why is this wrong?

Comment: Python has pointers just like most languages. They are just hidden to the casual user. Here is a blog post on the idea. http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/

Comment: @PeterH no, *Python does not have pointers*. The CPython implementation uses pointers, and if you understand C, the perhaps understanding some implementation details will help you understand how Python is working, but *Python itself* does not have pointers (outside of the `ctypes` FFI)

Comment: " I've tried doing a list copy to dereference the pointer passed by `initial_grid`" Is a *perfect* example of *why* talking about pointers can often lead to more confusion than not. Copying a list does not "dereference a pointer passed to the function", there *is no pointer*, and there certainly isn't any dereferencing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well... python does have pointers, of a sort. if you do `a=4;b=a;b=5;print a`, it'll return 5.

Comment: I do agree that there are no 'pointers' in python, however variables act like pointers when referencing a complex data type. And no there is no dereferencing, but if you keep passing the value of a variable to another variable without explicitly calling copy or deepcopy the variable is passing a reference (similar to a pointer, but not exactly the same) to the following variable. IMO this can cause a host of problems for people new to python that could be avoided if when being taught python they think of variables as pointers to memory.

Comment: @JakobLovern Firstly, no, it *prints 4*. That is not a pointer. You are just incorrectly demonstrating the way Python assignment works. Again, *there are no pointers in Python* (except in the `ctypes` foreign-function library, but that is not really relevant).

Comment: @PeterH NO. Python variabels **do not act like pointers to memory**. Indeed, your *own mistaken example* perfectly demonstrates why they do **not act that way**. IOW: `a=4;b=a;b=5;print a` **prints 4** IOW, while *yes*, in CPython, everything is essentially a pointer to a `Py_Object` struct, that doesn't mean that the semantics of Python assignment will work like the semantics of C-pointers.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not my example... Also complex data types... `a = [];
b = a;
b.append(12);
print a` prints `[12]`

Comment: @PeterH whoops, sorry, got confused with the screen names.

Comment: There are no "complex data types" in Python. The semantics for Python variables works *exactly the same* for *all Python objects*. In other words, `x = 300; y = x; id(x) == id(y)`. That works no matter the object you assign to `x`, and is the reason your example works the way it does. In Python `int` objects are just as much full-fledged objects as `list` objects, they just happen to lack any mutator methods. If you are willing to engage in some serious dark magic, you *can* actually change the value of `int` objects, and the changes will be reflected.

Comment: @PeterH but anyway, if you simply want to say that Python variables act like you are passing around pointers to python objects, that is true and I cannot disagree. I still think it is much more confusing (unless you are coming directly form a C background) than simply learning Python semantics on their own terms.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right. There is no 'complex data type'. I was using the wrong term. What I meant was immutable data types. I realise I am biased (and wrong) when it comes to referring to python variables as pointers (I learned to program in c/c++). They act like pointers but should not be called pointers. Thank you for clarifying my clear as mud comments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to learn more about dark magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list(initial_grid)` makes a shallow copy of your list. The inner lists are not copied.

Demo:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2], [0, 0]]
>>> c = list(l)
>>> l is c
False
>>> all(x is y for x,y in zip(l, c))
True
>>> c[0][0] = 5
>>> c
[[5, 2], [0, 0]]
>>> l
[[5, 2], [0, 0]]
```

If you want a deep copy, use `copy.deepcopy`. Or for a 2D list, write

```
>>> d = [sub[:] for sub in l]
>>> d[0][0] = 7
>>> d
[[7, 2], [0, 0]]
>>> l
[[5, 2], [0, 0]]
```

Also, your lingo is off. We don't have pointers in Python. We have names and values.